# Computing determinant

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, determinant

Let $$ A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1^{4} & x_2^{4} & x_3^{4} \\
x_1^{2} & x_2^{2} & x_3^{2} \\
1 &1 &1
  \end{bmatrix}
.$$ I want to show that the $$\det A \times  \frac{1}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)(x_2-x_3)} = x_1^2x_2+x_1^2x_3+x_2^2x_3+x_1x_2^2+x_1x_3^2+x_2x_3^2+2x_1x_2x_3.$$

The determinant of $A$ is trivial but trying to manipulate $\frac{1}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)(x_2-x_3)}$ is where I am having some problems.

We can think of $$\frac{1}{(x_1-x_2)} = \frac{1}{x_1(1-\frac{x_2}{x_1})}=\frac{1}{x_1}(1+ \frac{x_2}{x_1}+\frac{x_2^2}{x_1^2}+\cdots)$$ but I still dont end up getting the answer after multplying the whole thing out. Is there a trick to this? any hint will be appreciated.

P.S (Combinatorics): This is an expression from the definition of Schur Functions.

Comment: By replacing $x_i^2$ with $z_i$ you get a Vandermonde matrix, which is associated to an interpolation problem.

Comment: Just thinking out loud:  You could subtract the 2nd column from the 1st (and the 3rd from the 2nd.)  Then when you work out the det, you get some difference of squares-y things which might work well with your denominator.

Comment: @B.Goddard Thanks a lot. Done :)